# Show Variations as radio buttons - and to check selected radio

Tags: jquery, woocommerce

I want to replace variations dropdown with radio selectors.
The below code does this, but the selected radio is not checked (with a dot) How can I show the radio as selected?
[image]

The code from [here](https://codedcommerce.com/woo/change-variation-drop-downs-to-radio-buttons/)

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product', function() {
 
    // Variable Products Only
    global $product;
    if( ! $product || ! $product->is_type( 'variable' ) ) {
        return;
    }
 
    // Inline jQuery
    ?>
    <script>
        jQuery( document ).ready( function( $ ) {
            $( ".variations_form" )
                .on( "wc_variation_form woocommerce_update_variation_values", function() {
                $( "label.generatedRadios" ).remove();
                $( "table.variations select" ).each( function() {
                    var selName = $( this ).attr( "name" );
                    $( "select[name=" + selName + "] option" ).each( function() {
                        var option = $( this );
                        var value = option.attr( "value" );
                        if( value == "" ) { return; }
                        var label = option.html();
                        var select = option.parent();
                        var selected = select.val();
                        var isSelected = ( selected == value )
                            ? " checked=\"checked\"" : "";
                        var selClass = ( selected == value )
                            ? " selected" : "";
                        var radHtml
                            = `<input name="${selName}" type="radio" value="${value}" />`;
                        var optionHtml
                            = `<label class="generatedRadios${selClass}">${radHtml} ${label}</label>`;
                        select.parent().append(
                            $( optionHtml ).click( function() {
                                select.val( value ).trigger( "change" );
                            } )
                        )
                    } ).parent().hide();
                } );
            } );
        } );
    </script>
    <?php
} );
```

Comment: What html is rendered to the browser ([tag:php], or [tag:woocommerce] is irrelevant since you’re asking about client side functionality)?

Comment: maybe, personally I like context. Can you help?